Let $X=\tiny\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\tiny\begin{bmatrix} -1 &2&3 \\0&1&6\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$. Find $k$ st $X^{T}A^{k}X=[33]$.

Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 &2&3 \\0&1&6\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}.\ $ Find $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $X^{T}A^{k}X=[33]$.

Given Solution: $A^n=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&3n\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ if $n$ is even and $A^n=\begin{bmatrix}-1&2&3(2-n)\\0&1&6\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ if $n$ is odd
But It require me to first find $6$ matrices $A^2, A^3, A^4, A^5, A^6 , A^7$ to get pattern matrix $A$ is following. And it was given in exam which require it to solve within $2$ minutes.
Using above method I am getting $k=10$
My doubt: Is there any easy method to solve this problem?
Note: Where $X^{T}$ denotes Transpose of $X$

It's not very clear to me what you need to find, can you clarify a little?

I've rephrased the question as I understood it @SigmaAlgebra

The value of $k$ that makes $X^{T}A^{k}X=33$ is when $k=10$

@AderinsolaJoshua How did you obtained?

Are you absolutely sure about $2$ minutes? Or it's $2$ minutes on average, like you can pay the problem $10$ minutes if have done the rest of the exam faster than $2$ minutes per problem? What tools are allowed, like pen and paper? )

Note that $$
X^TBX = \sum_{i,j=1}^n X_iX_jB_{ij} = \sum_{i,j=1}^n B_{ij}
$$
for any square matrix $B$ and $X = [1,1,\ldots,1]^T$ the corresponding vector of all ones. So $X^TAX$ is the sum of entries of $A$.
Side by side, I'd observe that if I wanted to take higher powers of $A$, linear algebra would tell me that it's easiest to use the binomial theorem with appropriately broken up parts. So in this case, I'd think of writing $$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix}
0&2&3\\0&0&6\\0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}= D+N
$$
I observe that $A^2 = D^2+N^2+DN+ND$. Each of these matrices are fairly easy to compute : $$
D^2 = I, N^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
0&0&12\\0&0&0\\0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}, DN = \begin{pmatrix} 
0&-2&-3 \\
0&0&6\\
0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix},
ND = \begin{pmatrix}
0&2&-3 \\
0&0&-6\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
So, $$
A^2 = I + \begin{pmatrix}
0&0&6\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0 
\end{pmatrix}
=I+N'.
$$
where $N'$, if you notice, has the amazing property that $N'^2 = 0$, and that $IN' = N'I$. Thus, the binomial theorem for powers of matrices, which applies when matrices commute, can be used in this case.
Therefore, when I do $A^{2k} = (A^2)^k$ and use the appropriate binomial theorem, $$(A^2)^k = (I+N')^k=\sum_{m=0}^k \binom{k}{m}N'^m,$$
only the $m=0$ and $m=1$ terms remain. So, $$
A^{2k} = I+kN'.
$$
In particular, the sum of entries of $A^{2k}$ is the sum of entries of these two matrices, which is $3 + 6k$. We require that $3+6k = 33$, so $k=5$ and the required power of $A$ is $2\times 5 = 10$.
Note, furthermore, that $$
A^{2k+1} = A^{2k}A = (I+kN')A = A + kN'A
$$
so it's easy to calculate these powers as well, in case the even powers are not enough to finish the answer.

Since $A$ is a upper triangular matrix, then
$A^{k} =\begin{bmatrix} (-1)^{k} &\alpha &\beta \\0&1^{k}&\gamma \\0&0&(-1)^{k}\end{bmatrix}\ $ where $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma \} \in f(k)$
$X^{T}A^{k}X=33$ shows $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and multiplying $A^{k}$ by $X$ and its transpose $X^{T}$ means summing all entities in $A^{k}$ because $X$ contains only unity
$X^{T}A^{k}X = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha+\beta+\gamma+(-1)^{k}+(-1)^{k}+1^{k} \end{bmatrix}$
Then I used your formula for $A^{k}$ in the question and got $k$ to be $10$

My solution is general, but not fast at all, so it's probably not what is intended.
To compute the powers of a matrix one usually has to compute the Jordan Normal Form or (if lucky) the diagonalization. This is because powers of Diagonal matrices and Jordan Block are easy to compute (have canonical forms), and in general
$$A=SJS^{-1}\implies A^n=SJ^nS^{-1}.$$
In this case you are ``unlucky'', as $A$ has a double eigenvalue and it's JNF is given by $A=SJS^{-1}$ where
$$S=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1/3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\quad J=\begin{pmatrix}-1 &1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
and the general formula for
$$J^n=\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^n &(-1)^{n+1}n & 0\\ 0 & (-1)^n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
